# VPN Redirection based on specific domain and IP

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, mac, host

I have a VPN connection on my mac and I try to redirect (1) only some IP range and (2) domain throw VPN connection.

1. I achieved to redirect all IP range from `192.168.11.0/24` through VPN by creating a file `/etc/ppp/ip-up` and write it :

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   /sbin/route add -net 192.168.11.0/24 -interface ppp0
   ```
2. For the redirection of all hostname from a `domain` (ie. *.domain) to the VPN, I tried to define the DNS Name Server address in the parameters of the VPN connection but it doesn't work (cf. picture).

Is there another way to (a) redirect all *.domain to the VPN or (b) use firstly the remote DNS server ?

Many thanks

[image]